# Broadcast listener using Java?

Tags: java, sockets, broadcast

I have a DP(data processor, java code) running in my network and few C clients. Client needs to communicate to the DP for data exchange. Client need to discover the DP using broadcast discovery. Client will broadcast a message to which DP will listen and response for availability. I'm not sure how to add listener in Java for the broadcast messages, I tried using DatagramSocket but it asks for port number? DP should listen to broadcast message received on any port.

Comment: Check this http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless clients are using something like ICMP, they do need a port too. In a normal TCP/IP stack broadcast and multicast is done with UDP (yes, that's  `DatagramSocket` in Java-speak), thus a need for the port number. Just pick a port that you like, of make it flexible and provide a configuration option for both the server and the clients.

There are other options of course like [DNS `SRV` records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record), [multicast DNS/Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS), custom IP protocols, etc. but those are much harder to deal with.